# ValueError: Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "unit-4" python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I just tried web scraping using python, Beautifulsoup, in order to fetch a url of a product from the shopping site.

Here I provide my simple code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

root_url = 'http://www.flipkart.com'
index_url = root_url + '/tablets'

def get_item_url():
    response = requests.get(index_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
    return [a.attrs.get('href') for a in soup.select('div.product-unit unit-    4 browse-product-section a[href^=/digiflip-pro-et701-tablet]') 


print(get_item_url())
```

By run this program generate an error like this:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1300, in select
'Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "%s"' % token)
ValueError: Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "unit-4"
```

How can I solve the this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the Beautiful Soup documentation, I see that putting spaces between attributes in `select()` searches for tags *beneath* other tags.  So your `select()` is looking for an attribute called `unit-4` somewhere beneath `div.product-unit`, and then it's looking for `browse-product-section` underneath `unit-4`.  There is no such attribute present, so it returns an error.

The attributes in your `select()` are actually the names of HTML classes that are present on that web page, so you'd have to append a `.` to each of them to find them.  However, I think what you're really looking for is something more like:

```
return [a.attrs.get('href') for a in soup.select('div.product-unit a[href^=/digiflip-pro-et701-tablet]')]
```

which looks for an href underneath that div and returns

```
['/digiflip-pro-et701-tablet/p/itme27y5v2ws5cfm?pid=TABDWMDPGHPNYND7', '/digiflip-pro-et701-tablet/p/itme27y5v2ws5cfm?pid=TABDWMDPGHPNYND7', '/digiflip-pro-et701-tablet/p/itme27y5v2ws5cfm?pid=TABDWMDPGHPNYND7&ref=70ca8997-80a5-412d-9b94-6d5fb55f1277', '/digiflip-pro-et701-tablet/p/itme27y5v2ws5cfm?pid=TABDWGBMYSEMWHUY&ref=70ca8997-80a5-412d-9b94-6d5fb55f1277']
```

Incidentally, you could also replace `div.product-unit` with `unit-4`, or even do `select('a[href^=/digiflip-pro-et701-tablet]')` by itself, and you'd get the same output.