# Python BS4 Unsupported format: White space in attribute selector

Tags: python, css, beautifulsoup

I am beginning web scraping with BeautifulSoup in Python.

Website I am trying to parse

```
"http://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/computers-software/techmahindra/TM4"
```

My code as below

```
previous_close = content.select(".gD_12 PB3");
```

I have the following error when the line is interpreted

```
    previous_close = content.select(".gD_12 PB3");
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1313, in select
    'Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "%s"' % token)
ValueError: Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "PB3"
```

Though it was explained specific to that context, I am unable to apply it to my code.

[ValueError: Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "unit-4" python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168274/valueerror-unsupported-or-invalid-css-selector-unit-4-python)

Comment: get rid of the period in your select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message suggests, your current CSS selector expression is not valid.

`gD_12` and `PB3` are considered two separate CSS classes. Use `.` for each CSS class to match by multiple classes :

```
previous_close = content.select(".gD_12.PB3");
```

Explanation for your CSS selector along with some other variant to contranst :

- `.gD_12.PB3` : reads "*select element having both class `gD_12` and `PB3`*".
- `.gD_12 .PB3` : reads "*find element having class `gD_12`, then select descendant of it having class `PB3`*".
- `.gD_12 PB3` : reads "*find element having class `gD_12`, then select descendats of it using selector `PB3`*". `PB3` is invalid CSS selector and will trigger `Unsupported or invalid CSS selector` error.